# how to sum the items of array of json objects?

Tags: php, json

I faced a problem while i was trying to do the sum of array of object

i tried to access the propreties of the array and do the sum but it did not work.here the result :

```
<?php
header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *");
header("Access-Control-Allow-Credentials: true ");
header('Access-Control-Allow-Methods: GET, PUT, POST, DELETE, OPTIONS');
header("Access-Control-Allow-Headers: X-Custom-Header, Origin, Content- 
Type , Authorisation , X-Requested-With");
header("Content-Type: application/json; charset=UTF-8 ");
$json = file_get_contents('php://input');
$decoded = json_decode($json, true);
$tab = $decoded['tab'];
var_dump($tab);
$sum = 0;
foreach ($tab as $item) {
$sum += $tab->prix;
}
var_dump($sum);

?>
```

i expect the sum to be the sum of prix proprety in the array

Comment: Did it throw an error? What were the result you did get?

Comment: use `item` like  `$sum += $item->prix;`

Comment: Please, post the `JSON` input. And `$sum += $tab->prix;` probably is `$sum += item["prix"];`. You decode the input JSON as an array.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have not used foreach iterator

```
foreach ($tab as $item) {
    $sum += $item['prix']; // $item should be here which is iterator not $tab
}
```

> **Note:-** When TRUE, returned objects will be converted into associative arrays.

It means, when you pass true in json_decode as the second parameter it returns an array, not an object. So `->` operator won't work.

Comment: did not work , the rsult is <b>Notice</b>:  Trying to get property 'prix' of non-object in <b>C:\xampp\htdocs\SmartLibrary\api\price.php</b> on line <b>16</b><br />
int(0)

Comment: for idea the array is array of objects and it ha sa field called prix which i should do the sum

Answer (score 0):

Possible solution without foreach:

```php
$json = '{"tab":[{"prix": 10},{"prix":20}]}';
$decoded = json_decode($json, true);

array_sum(array_column($decoded['tab'], 'prix'));
```